# Program that gets input and reverse the string

Tags: loops, reverse, charat

My code is suppose to use loops only, I am suppose to make a string reverse and return that reverse value. I have a problem return the reverse value and I have no clue how to do it.`

> public static String reverseString(String str){

```
for(int i =str.length()-1;i>=0;i--)



return str.charAt(i);// This wont return the value, gives me a error
                             // any tips?

}
```

Comment: Why are you passing `int i` to the charAt() function?  It should just be `i` to indicate which index to get the character from.  Also, I think your for loop should go down to >= 0, not > 0.  You want to include that last character

Comment: thanks so much, but do you have any clue how can i do the return statement, I am not allowed to have a system.out.println, I took out the int it still wont work.:p

Comment: You could declare a string before the loop, concatenation each character during your loop and then return the string at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you use Java you can change your code to this:

```
public static String reverseString(String str){

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i =str.length()-1;i>=0;i--){

        sb.append(str.charAt(i));
    }

    return sb.toString();

}
```

The change is that you create a StringBuilder object. The code you posted tries to return the first char you extract from your string which is not what you want. You want to build the string in reverse, so in each iteration you add the next reversed char to your StringBuilder, and when the loop terminates, you return the string representation of the StringBuild by using toString().

You can do this implementation smarter and faster, but I assume that this task is part of a learning process, so it is more important that you understand why your code should not place a return statement in a loop, when you actually want the loop to iterate multiple times and save each intermediate result before returning anything.

Documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

### UPDATE:

Based on **ohiodoug**'s comment about StringBuilder it would be appropriate to also show how it is done without the StringBuilder class:

```
import java.lang.StringBuilder;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String [ ] args){

        String resultSimple = simpleReverseString("Hello World!");
        String resultSB = betterReverseString("Hello World!");
        System.out.println(resultSimple);
        System.out.println(resultSB);
        //Prints:
        //!dlroW olleH
        //!dlroW olleH
    }

    //Simple string concatenation. 
    //Uses the += operator.
    //Since s is already a String we don't need to use
    //toString() on it.
    public static String simpleReverseString(String str){

        String s = "";

        for(int i =str.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
            //s += str.charAt(i) is equal to
            //s = s + str.charAt(i)
            s += str.charAt(i);
        }
        return s;
    }        

    //Same as simpleReverseString, but uses the StringBuilder class
    public static String betterReverseString(String str){

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i =str.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
            sb.append(str.charAt(i));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }     
}
```

Comment: While you're using a StringBuilder... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse()

Comment: I assume you refer to the StringBuilder.reverse() method? I don't think that would help OP with his original problem since he must use a for loop. I guess it is a programming assignment.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer**:

```
public static String reverseString(String str){
     char[] temp = new char[str.length()];
     for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
         temp[i] = str.charAt(str.length() - (i + 1));
     }
     return new String(temp);
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Can you explain to me how do I enter this into eclipse 0.0 
Everything between the brackets are in red
I use eclipse

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize you were using java since this looks so much like c#. I'll update the answer if you want, but you already accepted something else as the solution.

Comment: Updated the answer from a c# implementation to a Java implementation. If this was a homework assignment, I doubt using built-in libraries like StringBuilder is what your professor wants to see.

Comment: You are correct. I have updated my answer to also include a solution where StringBuilder is not used.